# Service Area Generation using QGIS 3.22.3

Tags: qgis, network-analysis

I am trying to generate a service area using 62K points, located along a road centerline, allocating out a distance of 762 metres from each point.

Can you do this in QGIS?

I am only seeing single point generation, but I'm sure that I am missing something.

Comment: Are you trying to create points along a line at an interval of 762m?  Or are you trying to do something else?  If that's what you're doing, you need 'Points along geometry' in the Vector Geometry toolbox.